# Flash plays hidden in Firefox v14

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox, colorbox

Using ColorBox to play Flash video embedded simply with via `<object><embed>` in a custom player as well as through a streaming service within FlowPlayer.

**Flash continues to play regardless of CSS hidden state** (`display:none`) when an "inline" ColorBox is closed. This is not true in any other browser, and not true in older versions of Firefox. *FF seems to be the culprit across operating systems as well.*

The only [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806032) I've found that can address the problem use `.remove()` to kill off the video. While this could be bound to ColorBox closing it doesn't seems feasible to create an agnostic solution for multiple flash popups on a page and across a site.

Wondering what else I could be missing to stop this behavior?

Comment: Found another victim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663230/video-gets-hidden-via-javascript-but-already-starts-to-play-autplay-mode-even

Comment: Looks like some folks have tried to tackle this by manipulating the object/embed/param properties, but that's rather error prone. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/find-manipulate-object-embed AND http://forum.jquery.com/topic/add-attributes-to-embed-tag

Comment: Apparently be aware of attr() issues with objects and embeds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173012/jquery-object-embed-element-issue-with-attr-method